# 2 Raycasts In Different Directions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a raycast constantly and I want it to come out of where the player is facing. I tried this and it made 2 rays one up and one going forward but slighty down.

Like this: [image]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Toast : MonoBehaviour
{
    Ray ray;
    RaycastHit raycastHit;
    public Camera cam;

    void Start()
    {
        cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
    }

    void Update()       
    {
        ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward * 1000);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out raycastHit))
        {
            if (raycastHit.transform.tag=="Death")
            {
                Debug.Log("DIE OF BUTTER");         
            }
        }
       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you make sure there aren't any `Toast` components elsewhere in the scene? That could be causing the 2nd ray to be drawn.

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as correct so it's taken off the list of unanswered questions

Comment: Funny this was the one problem